# Disabling keyboard '\' key autotype and fixing

Tags: keyboard, laptop, login

I've Dell Latitude D620 laptop, with BackTrack installed. For the fast few days, it's automatically typing the <kbd>\</kbd> automatically without any break. I tried to break it by <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>. However it pauses for a few seconds and continues in next line.

I can't even login to system because of the issue.

I believe it can't be a malware problem. Any possible solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, it does not look like malware -- it looks more like a broken keyboard. Try to boot the LiveCD and see what happens.

Comment: This idea didn't strike on my mind. I'll update soon!

Comment: The problem is with hardware. Many keys failed in live mood too. Thanks the idea.